# Windows task scheduler: save a text file

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, notepad

Gist: I want a task scheduled that just saves an existing text file every 15 minutes.

I used the task scheduler to create a task and when I'm in the area where I add actions, I'm stuck. I know, **this sounds stupid.**

I chose start a program and set the program to "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe". I don't know what to put in the Arguments or Start in. I'm thinking I should put the path to the file, but that would just open it, right? I want it saved. I tried adding a -s /s or whatever but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Save what file? With what contents? You might need to give some more detail on what exactly you're trying to accomplish - there's likely to be other ways to do it...

Comment: I mentioned an existing text file. No modifications, so same content. I just need it to be saved, that's all.

Comment: If it's an already existing file, and there are no modifications and no new content, then it's already saved. What will saving it again, and again, and again accomplish?

Comment: I just need to do it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting. Try moving file to itself by "cmd /c move file.txt file.txt". You are correct that opening file in notepad would need you to save it. however I would like to say no file, even if some changes being made to it, need to be saved. In my understanding if any application that is making change to the file is actually writing to it permanently.